# How to run a script while turning on sas

Tags: sas, include

I have a ready to run script in sas which maps me all the libraries I need to use. What i usually do is turning on sas and then lunch this script through an include command like this:

```
%include "C:\Users\lucai\Google Drive\serie a\macro\include\mapping.sas";
```

Now when I press the sas icon for launching sas I'd like to launch `mapping.sas` program automatically without lunching that line of code.

I know is possible, because I used to do it, but I forgot how ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways.

Create a personal `autoexec.sas` in your `%USERPROFILE%` folder.  Default SAS startup icon should find it.  Add SAS code to your autoexec.sas

Create an alternate `autoexec-whatever.sas` autoexec file.
Create a new SAS icon and append the `-autoexec <path-to-whatever>` command line option to specify the custom autoexec.

Create a new SAS icon and append to the command line the option `-INITSTMT "… SAS Code …"`  to specify the statement to submit after autoexec processing

[SAS Help Center](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=allprodsle&docsetTarget=syntaxByType-systemOption.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p0m11am0iczz9pn1aeerznbi58u7p1uuzonxjtnxwon1tgm27729dljx) documents the many options.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can add your %INC to AUTOEXEC.SAS

[Introduction to the SAS Autoexec File](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=hostwin&docsetTarget=p0bmj7wjme32ayn1h4wim7trkhp6.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n1bp9r0h4u35nyn13mnhoxan1wn1)

Comment: ok but i cant' find autoexe.sas. you know where is usually located?

Answer (score 1):

Add that line to your autoexec file.  Or just use that file as your autoexec file. In general if you start SAS from the command line it will look first in the current directory for a file named autoexec.sas and run that code.  But there are other places it will work and you can override the default search by adding the -autoexec option to the command line.

Here is one write up for how it works on Windows.
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/69955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0bmj7wjme32ayn1h4wim7trkhp6.htm
Similar process will happen on Unix systems.  Although on Unix it will check your home directory after checking the current directory. It is not clear to me that Windows has the concept of a home directory and anyway the link above does not mention it the list of where SAS will look.